# MySql PHP PDO get single row and split to seperate values?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So how do I get single values in each seperate `$stmt->bindColumn(3, $username);`? What I am trying to do is set values in text fields in a form: `name`, `username`, and so on.

I pull the sandbox data from a table with:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE namn = 'sven' AND lösenord = ' ' ORDER BY datetime LIMIT 1
```

```
try {
    $sql = "SELECT namn FROM user_view";

    $stmt = $dbh->getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results=$stmt->fetchAll();

    $stmt->bindColumn(1, $email);
    $stmt->bindColumn(2, $name);
    $stmt->bindColumn(3, $username);
    $stmt->bindColumn(4, $password);
} 

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}

<input id="text" name="text" value="<?php echo $username ?>" type="text" class="form-control">
```

Comment: `SELECT namn FROM user_view` should probably be `SELECT email,name,username,password FROM user_view`

Comment: You really shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text!

Comment: @Steven You are absolutly right about the password offcource. I can se my question is abit unclear and the answers focus on the wrong parts. I am playing arround within an sandbox and the rigt collumn name is date, time, name, and so on. No password in plain text and its not relevent in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table structure is something like...

```
user_view
    > id
    > name
    > email
    > username
    > password
```

And that you want to loop though all users (as you don't have a `WHERE` clause)...

```
$pdo = $dbh->getInstance();          // Get PDO instance

$sql   = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM user_view
    WHERE name = ? 
";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);        // Prepare query
$query->execute([$_POST["name"]]);   // Execute query and bind value to place holder (I've assumed it's coming from POST user input)

// Loop through result set
$user = $stmt->fetchObject();

// Access the columns like
    # echo $user->name;
    # echo $user->email;
    # echo $user->username;
    # echo $user->password;

// For example
echo "<input id='user_name' name='user_name' value='{$user->name}' type='text' class='form-control'>";
```

### N.B.

You shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text - it's a major security risk.

You can use the following to hash a password on registration...

```
$password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

And to verify...

```
if( password_verify($_POST["password"], $db_password) ){
    // Success, do something...
}
```

Comment: Sorry Steven.
I put some more info in my question i realised was missing.My bad...

Comment: @SvanteStenberg So the query in the code should actually have the `WHERE`?